# QGIS 3 crashes when adding a PostGIS view as a map layer?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, sql-view

I am trying to load a PostGIS view `public.view1` into QGIS (3.6) as follows (per [Add PostGIS layer to QGIS via Python Console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300195)):

```
tablename = "view1"
geometrycol = "geom"

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "user", "user", "")
uri.setDataSource ("public", tablename, geometrycol)
vlayer=QgsVectorLayer (uri .uri(False), tablename, "postgres")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

The view is created from a source table:

```
create view view1 as select * from my_table;
```

Both the source table `my_table` and the view `view1` can be loaded via the QGIS 3 GUI manually without a problem. But when loading the view programmatically using the above code, QGIS crashes on the last line:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

The same code works fine on the source table. And this is with PostgreSQL 11.3, PostGIS 2.5, and QGIS 3.6.

*Has anyone else encountered similar problems and know of a solution?*

Comment: does it work if you 'unroll' the last line, e.g. `inst = QgsProject.instance()  inst.addMapLayer(vlayer)` ?

Comment: @StevenKay Thanks. I just tested "unroll" version, and QGIS still crashes.