# How to load valid PostgreSQL QgsVectorLayer

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, postgresql, vector-layer

**Note:**

> This is NOT a closed question. The following links does NOT provide an
> answer to the solution:
>
> [Add PostGIS layer to QGIS via Python Console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300195/add-postgis-layer-to-qgis-via-python-console)
>
> The Vector layer still remains invalid with the recommended changes
> being made.
>
> [PyQGIS QgsVectorLayer() Loading Invalid Layer in Standalone Python Script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308398/pyqgis-qgsvectorlayer-loading-invalid-layer-in-standalone-python-script)
>
> I can also confirm my QgsApplication prefixpath is correct

I have a QGIS script I am writing in PyCharm, that I am trying to load a vector layer stored in a PostgreSQL database. When I print the layer's isValid() method I get False. Here is my code:

```
from qgis.core import *

db_client = 'postgres'
db_host = 'localhost'
db_port = '5432'
db_name = 'database'
db_user = 'user'
db_password = 'pass123'
db_schema = 'public'
tablename = 'Geo_Layer'
geometrycol = 'geom'
tract_number_index = 3

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
# I have also tried the following:
# qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()

geo_uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
geo_uri.setConnection(db_host, db_port, db_name, db_user, db_password)

geo_uri.setDataSource(db_schema, tablename, geometrycol, '', 'id')
# I have also tried the following
# geo_uri.setDataSource(db_schema, tablename, geometrycol)

geo_layer = QgsVectorLayer(geo_uri.uri(False), "Test", "postgres")
# Other configurations I have tried
# geo_layer = QgsVectorLayer(geo_uri.uri(), "Test", "postgres")
# geo_layer = QgsVectorLayer(geo_uri.uri(), "Test", "ogr")
# geo_layer = QgsVectorLayer(geo_uri.uri(False), "Test", "ogr")
# A working version using an exported geopackage
# geo_layer = QgsVectorLayer('/home/<path to geopackage>/geo_layer.gpkg|layername=geo_layer', "Test", "ogr")
print(geo_layer.isValid())

qgs.exitQgis()
```

I have provided the other QgsVectorLayer configurations I have tried. All print that the layer is not valid.

QGIS Version: 3.16.3-Hannover Python Version: 3.8.5 Ubuntu Version: 20.04.02 LTS

I have check my credentials with DBeaver and I am able to connect.

I have made sure I have the correct QgsApplication prefixPath by opening my QGIS Desktop, opening the Python Console and executing the following:

```
QgsApplication.prefixPath() 
'/usr'
```

Also in QGIS Desktop the specific vector layer I am trying to validate, I can export that layer into a GeoPackage and connect to it and validate the Vector Layer. So I think I have the correct QgsApplication configuration.

```
geo_layer = QgsVectorLayer('/home/<path to geopackage>/geo_layer.gpkg|layername=geo_layer', "Test", "ogr")
```

This is the workaround I have in place, but I would like to connect directly to my PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Used your code with my own db parameters and your sample works. To be sure, `tablename = 'Geo_Layer'` is not `tablename = 'geo_layer'` ? Did you run your sample in PyQGIS console commenting the standalone code part to validate your layer and its parameters?

Comment: @ThomasG77 The table value of Geo_Layer is correct. commenting out the standalone code results in the layer being invalid. Is there a way to load the Layer in my QGIS Desktop Project in the Python Console and verify it's configuration? Since I know that vector layer is valid. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Go to see how open your file and run it in PyQGIS Desktop console https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/pyqgis-in-a-day.html#where-can-you-use-python-in-qgis#hello-world

Comment: Sorry, what a mistake when sharing previous link https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/pyqgis-in-a-day.html#hello-world

Comment: @ThomasG77 I am able to get the layer with the following `QgsProject.instance().mapLayer('<layer_id>').source()` which gives me the connection info. it seems there are some other parameters like sslmode, srid, type, and checkPrimaryKeyUnicity I will try to add these

Comment: Not need, just run the code from https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ThomasG77/e2997114ac549a3b833737fb36f508b1/raw/3658b33790e244ac915b547ec7a9a55988cc3fb7/debug-gis-stackexchange-q-386583.py (same as your with standalone part) in the PyQGIS Desktop QGIS console. Change until valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting your geometry column is not named geom. Try wkb_geometry.